# Remove file name portion of local file URL

Tags: regex, macos, bash, awk, sed

I have an HTML document which includes links to a hundred or so local files.  I want to use either sed, awk or perl (in that preferred order) to remove the filename portion of the URL up to the last backslash in the URL.  In the example below I'm only showing a portion of the HTML code forming the path of the local file.

Example:

```
<a href="file:///Volumes/VolumeName/Download/Mac%20Software/CompanyName/SoftwarePackageName.dmg">
```

After Processing Example:

```
<a href="file:///Volumes/VolumeName/Download/Mac%20Software/CompanyName/">
```

In testing I have tried different regular expression combinations to accomplish this however I'm only getting ".dmg" or it and everything to the left of .dmg and I really only want to remove the "SoftwarePackageName.dmg" portion.  BTW In some cases it's "SoftwarePackageName.zip" and there may be a space in the "CompanyName" or "SoftwarePackageName.dmg" shown as "%20".  I've also reviewed "Questions that may already have your answer" shown when creating this post.

EDIT: I appreciate the time taken to try and help and certainly understand the difficulty when due to policy I cannot provide more then the example I did and as such I'll just manually edit the html document.  I've already taken to much of my time and others on this.  Will just have to do more reading on regex for the next time.  Thanks to all that contributed. :)

Comment: "There will come a day when people no longer use regex to parse HTML."

Comment: Perl has an html parser module.

Comment: @tripleee While I understand using regex is not always a magic bullet and can appreciate your comment nonetheless it does nothing to help with the issue at hand!  I could just easily manually edit the file, it's a one time thing at this point, however I learn nothing in the process that helps with other scripting tasks if I do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I want to say again how much I truly appreciate the time taken by those who tried to help!  Secondly, it pains me to have to say that nothing that was presented worked in the real-world application and I, at the least, attribute that to you all not having the actual file I wanted to modify to work with and sorry I was not allowed to provide it.  Yes your demos worked however unfortunately they were not at all representative of the actual html coding in the document and maybe because the "Generator" was "Cocoa HTML Writer" from a RTF Document this might have had something to do with it, just not sure at the moment.  Even if I took just one complete line that included the Example code, placing it by itself in a file and then processing it nonetheless all solutions presented failed.  I wish I could provide the file or take the time to figure out why in this real-world use it fails, however I can't.

Some background on the Document is when originally created as an RTF Document in TextEdit the FQP of the target file was included because the version of OS X would open the target file however in later versions of OS X it only opens Finder to the location of the target file.  As such there is no longer a need to use the FQP to the target file just the path to its location.  This actually makes it easier to update the RTF Document over time.  At times this RTF Document is exported to an HTML Document to be modified and then saved as an RTF Document.  As I mention earlier maybe the "Generator" being "Cocoa HTML Writer" from a RTF Document in TextEdit is in part to blame why processing failed with the proposed solutions.

Anyway the reason for my long winded reply is to put this issue in proper perspective and also explain how I resolved this issue.  As I had previously mentioned I was just going to manually edit the file however after the generous help already presented I wanted to find some automated solutions and I did.

The primary constant was the Example code previously presented so focusing only on it here is the command line I used to process the file.

```
grep -o 'file:///[^"]*' Build_Out_Template.html | rev | cut -d / -f 1 | rev | while read LINE; do sed -i "s/${LINE}//" Build_Out_Template.html; done
```

Using "grep -o 'file:///[^"]*'" enabled me to extract just the target portion of the lines in the document.  I piped it through rev to reverse the character order and piped it through cut which gave be only the portion up to the first slash in the reversed line (after the last slash in the original line) and then had to pipe it again through rev for obvious reasons.  It was then piped through a loop where sed used a very simple instruction vs a complex regex using literally just the SoftwarePackageName.dmg etc. file name. While much more time was spent on this then manually editing the file nonetheless I took it as a challenge and will remember that sometimes the thinking out-side-the-box solution is faster and easier and I'll remember this for some other application if/when needed.

Thanks again to all who tried to help, it's truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed 's|\(<a href="file:///[^>]*/\).*">|\1">|g'
```

Demo:

```
$ sed 's|\(<a href="file:///[^>]*/\).*\.\(dmg\|zip\)">|\1">|g' <<EOF
> <a href="file:///Volumes/VolumeName/Download/Mac%20Software/CompanyName/SoftwarePackageName.dmg">
> foo bar <a href="file:///Volumes/VolumeName/Download/Mac%20Software/CompanyName/SoftwarePackageName.dmg"> baz quux
> EOF
<a href="file:///Volumes/VolumeName/Download/Mac%20Software/CompanyName/">
foo bar <a href="file:///Volumes/VolumeName/Download/Mac%20Software/CompanyName/"> baz quux
```

Comment: I appreciate the time you took and while your code works on the example, nonetheless it does not work on the actual file as it does remove the "SoftwarePackageName.dmg" portion of the URL along with almost everything else on the line proceeding it and everything after it thus making the file unusable.

Comment: It works when I try it, it doesn't remove anything outside the link.

Comment: Yes as I previously it does work on the sample code however the documents contains much more html coding then just the snippet provided in the example and as such under that circumstance it removes everything on the line after "SoftwarePackageName.dmg" and a considerable amount of the line proceeding it far beyond the "<a href="file:" portion.

Comment: If you read my comment to Avinash Raj re: could you post the actual file content? suffice it to say that most lines in the html document have the example code already presented and that portion of the line is unique in that the URL portion of the link always ends in either .dmg or.zip and if a solution based solely on that example cannot be formulated I understand and appreciate the time you've already taken.  I could change all occurrences of .zip to .dmg prior to removing the "SoftwarePackageName.dmg" portion of the URL if that helps and then key in specifically on...

Comment: ... removing just the "SoftwarePackageName.dmg" portion.  In other works can it be formulated to just remove "SoftwarePackageName.dmg" regardless of what else exists on the line, which includes URL's to the Software Manufactures Website as well.

Comment: removing just the "SoftwarePackageName.dmg" portion.  In other works can it be formulated to just remove "SoftwarePackageName.dmg" regardless of what else exists on the line, which includes URL's to the Software Manufactures Website as well.

Comment: I've modified my regep so it only matches when the URL ends in `.dmg` or `.zip`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below sed command.

```
sed 's/\(<a href="[^."]*\/\)[^."\/]*\.[^."\/]*">/\1">/g' file
```

Comment: I appreciate the time you took and while your code works on the example, nonetheless it does not work on the actual file and did not remove the "SoftwarePackageName.dmg" portion of the URL.

Comment: could you post the actual file content?

Comment: Unfortunately no, this is an internal document template for doing controlled builds of OS X and software, as I would have to redact account info, passwords and serial numbers, etc. associated with to many of the programs.

Answer (score 0):

**modded**

I've deleted the previous `sed` regex (I have no way to test it).
Instead, I'm posting a expanded regex (verbose) that should help get you started.

```
 # Unknown extension: (<a\s+[^>]*?href\s*=\s*(["'])[^>]*?/)([^/."'>]+\.[^/."'>]+)\2
 # Known extension: (<a\s+[^>]*?href\s*=\s*(["'])[^>]*?/)([^/."'>]+\.dmg\b[^/."'>]*)\2
 # Replacement: $1$2     

 (                                     # (1 start), Tag and Url part to keep
      <a \s+ [^>]*? href \s* = \s* 
      ( ["'] )                              # (2), Quote
      [^>]*? 
      /                                     # End of directories
 )                                     # (1 end)
 (                                     # (3 start), Throw away filename
      [^/."'>]+                             # - Filename (not /."'> chars)
      \.                                    # - Dot

      # - Extension and parameters
      # ----------------------------
      # Use one of these lines (but not both)

      # Known extensions ->
      #dmg \b [^/."'>]* 

      # Unknown extensions ->
      [^/."'>]+ 
 )                                     # (3 end)
 \2                                    # Backref to Quote
```

Sed should not use much of a different substitute structure `s///g`.
It might be the case that you have to escape parenthesis meta characters. But I think that's
it for this regex. These regex are in the raw state.

Here they are used in a sample Perl program. It could easily be done useing Perl from the command line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = undef;

my $html = <DATA>;  # slurp in the entire file
my $htmlcopy = $html;

$html =~ s|(<a\s+[^>]*?href\s*=\s*(["'])[^>]*?/)([^/."'>]+\.[^/."'>]+)\2|\1\2|g;
print "Replaced using Unknown extensions:\n", $html, "\n";

$htmlcopy =~ s|(<a\s+[^>]*?href\s*=\s*(["'])[^>]*?/)([^/."'>]+\.dmg\b[^/."'>]*)\2|\1\2|g;
print "Replace using Known extensions:\n", $htmlcopy, "\n\n";


__DATA__

<a href="file:///Volumes/VolumeName/Download/Mac%20Software/CompanyName/SoftwarePackageName.dmg">
<a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://www.ielts.org/researchers/analysis-of-test-data/">
<a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://qiyas.sa/Sites/English/Tests/LanguageTests/Pages/Standardized-Test-for-English-Proficiency-(STEP).aspx">
<a rel="nofollow" class="external free" href="http://www.ielts.org/about_us.aspx">
<a href="/w/index.php?title=IELTS&amp;redirect=no" title="IELTS">
<a href="/wiki/File:IELTS_logo.svg" class="image">
<a href="/w/index.php?title=International_English_Language_Testing_System&amp;action=edit&amp;section=1" title="Edit section: IELTS characteristics">
<a href="/w/index.php?title=Band_score&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="Band score (page does not exist)">
<a href="/w/index.php?title=International_English_Language_Testing_System&amp;action=edit&amp;section=2" title="Edit section: IELTS test structure">
<a href="/wiki/University_of_St._Andrews" title="University of St. Andrews" class="mw-redirect">
<a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://bandscore.ielts.org/search.aspx">
<a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://www.bristol.ac.uk/university/governance/policies/admissions/language-requirements.html#toc05">
<a href="#cite_ref-11">
<a href="/wiki/Special:BookSources/1405833122" class="internal mw-magiclink-isbn">
```

Output >>

```
Replaced using Unknown extensions:

<a href="file:///Volumes/VolumeName/Download/Mac%20Software/CompanyName/">
<a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://www.ielts.org/researchers/analysis-of-test-data/">
<a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://qiyas.sa/Sites/English/Tests/LanguageTests/Pages/">
<a rel="nofollow" class="external free" href="http://www.ielts.org/">
<a href="/w/" title="IELTS">
<a href="/wiki/" class="image">
<a href="/w/" title="Edit section: IELTS characteristics">
<a href="/w/" class="new" title="Band score (page does not exist)">
<a href="/w/" title="Edit section: IELTS test structure">
<a href="/wiki/" title="University of St. Andrews" class="mw-redirect">
<a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://bandscore.ielts.org/">
<a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://www.bristol.ac.uk/university/governance/policies/admissions/">
<a href="#cite_ref-11">
<a href="/wiki/Special:BookSources/1405833122" class="internal mw-magiclink-isbn">


Replace using Known extensions:

<a href="file:///Volumes/VolumeName/Download/Mac%20Software/CompanyName/">
<a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://www.ielts.org/researchers/analysis-of-test-data/">
<a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://qiyas.sa/Sites/English/Tests/LanguageTests/Pages/Standardized-Test-for-English-Proficiency-(STEP).aspx">
<a rel="nofollow" class="external free" href="http://www.ielts.org/about_us.aspx">
<a href="/w/index.php?title=IELTS&amp;redirect=no" title="IELTS">
<a href="/wiki/File:IELTS_logo.svg" class="image">
<a href="/w/index.php?title=International_English_Language_Testing_System&amp;action=edit&amp;section=1" title="Edit section: IELTS characteristics">
<a href="/w/index.php?title=Band_score&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="Band score (page does not exist)">
<a href="/w/index.php?title=International_English_Language_Testing_System&amp;action=edit&amp;section=2" title="Edit section: IELTS test structure">
<a href="/wiki/University_of_St._Andrews" title="University of St. Andrews" class="mw-redirect">
<a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://bandscore.ielts.org/search.aspx">
<a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://www.bristol.ac.uk/university/governance/policies/admissions/language-requirements.html#toc05">
<a href="#cite_ref-11">
<a href="/wiki/Special:BookSources/1405833122" class="internal mw-magiclink-isbn">
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: How does it not provide an answer to the question ?

Comment: From page 16 of Sed and Awk Second Edition... "Enclosing the instruction in single quotes is not required in all cases but you should get in the habit of always doing it. The enclosing single quotes prevent the shell from interpreting special characters or spaces found in the editing instruction. (The shell uses spaces to determine individual arguments submitted to a program; characters that are special to the shell are expanded before the command is invoked.)"

Comment: Pressed the wrong key and it posted before I was finished commenting...  The reason I mentioned the quote from Sed and Awk Second Edition is because without the single quotes the instruction fails on OS X in a BASH shell.  Anyway even with the single quotes while the instruction executes it does not remove my intended target "SoftwarePackageName.dmg" from the URLs in the document.

Comment: I can assure you the regex is correct and works. Unfortunately all I can do is give you regex advice. I use Windows box, never used Linux so don't know sed command. It looks like parenthesis need to be escaped and I used the `s///g` form from Perl. I can show you a Perl example, or 1 liner for you to try. I don't think you realize the gorilla in the room is the regex, it should be tested on samples before you trust it to change your web page.